# 256 color mode xterm for MacOS X

Tags: macos, xterm

Is there any 256 color xterm for MacOS x? Like the one described below?
http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The xterm which Apple ship with OS X appears to support 256 colours - I just tested it with the test listed [here](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/). To run it, start Apple's X11 server (located in `/Applications/Utilities/X11`).

Answer (score 6):

Lion's "Terminal" app has 256 colors.

Answer (score 2):

Recent [SVN builds](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/download.shtml) of iTerm will do the job, just tested with xorg's script

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how can I make it to use Dark background as my default profile?

Comment: right click into the terminal window, select "Info...", change your colours and click "Update Default"

Comment: Thanks. Is there any LSCOLOR GENERATOR which generate color for 256 color terminals?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using iTerm2 and I love it!